# Stack Exchange branded courseware

Tags: discussion, blog, company

Is there any plan to implement - or maybe it's already in place somewhere - courses, especially about software development, using the same gamified, badge-based approach adopted in Q&A? I was thinking of projects like [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/?cid=181)

Comment: Related: [What does the recent sale of Stack Exchange mean for the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365050/289691), [State of the Stack Q2 2021 Blog Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366568/289691) (Stack Exchange, Inc. was bought by [Prosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus))

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer is no in the short term. Instead the company is showing third-party courseware ads. For details see

[Announcing more ways to learn and grow your skills](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/02/01/announcing-more-ways-to-learn-and-grow-your-skills/) from February 1, 2023

From the above link

> Online Course Recommendations is an additional step on our path to providing all the resources technologists need in one place, and we look forward to continuing to share new ways for users to learn and grow on Stack Overflow.

Related

- [CEO update: Eliminating obstacles to productivity, efficiency, and learning](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/31/ceo-update-eliminating-obstacles-to-productivity-efficiency-and-learning/) from January 31, 2023
- [We’re bringing advertisements for technology courses to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422723/1595451)