# How can SO's CEO claim to speak on behalf of all SO contributors?

Tags: discussion, company

Regarding [Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/), I see that [Prashanth Chandrasekar](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/pchandrasekar/) states

> "This is tremendously exciting news for our employees, our customers, our community members, and for our shareholders"

I am a community member: I was not asked for my opinion.

The statement also includes:

> How you use our site and our products will not change in the coming weeks or months

This fails to include *years*.

Can the new Stack Exchange confirm that the existing company will be monetized so that it is worth me investing in it?

Comment: Is it saying each group is excited about the news? or is it saying he believes they should be.

Comment: I mean... it would certainly *excite* a lot of people (*2nd definition:  In a higher energy state than normal*)

Comment: @Ollie OP here certainly seems excited by the news.

Comment: meh, corpspeak at its finest - these words bear as much meaning as jibberish. They probably thought that we will get all grumpy if left out of the enumeration of stakeholders.

Comment: One person deciding to speak on behalf of the entire community without asking isn't exactly unprecedented. That said, I'm pretty sure Kevin B is right and what's being said is that the news is both exciting and applicable to the mentioned groups. *This fails to include years.* Why would it include years? Even if the acquisition never happened they wouldn't promise to never change the site at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > "This is tremendously exciting news for our employees, our customers, our community members, and for our shareholders"

> I am a community member: I was not asked for my opinion.

I don't believe that this is really up to you. The site and its content won't actually change (nor will things like the community managers). *Nothing* should change for you or me, so I don't think it's worth arguing about it. It's just a statement. It is not saying that every member of Stack Exchange is suddenly worshiping the new management, it is simply saying that the majority of us are OK with this new change (and excited for the future).  What's done is done - life's not fair.

I would also like to refer to Shog9's answer on the recent and relevant question [What does the recent sale of Stack Exchange mean for the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365050/what-does-the-recent-sale-of-stack-exchange-mean-for-the-community) :

> Stack Overflow is all grown up ... Its adolescent innocence is gone, and what happens now must happen with intent and purpose. We'll have to see what that ultimately means...

Overall, in my opinion, this isn't something that we can control.

> Can the new Stack Exchange confirm that the existing company will be monetized so that it is worth me investing in it?

This is a multi-billion dollar purchase you're talking about. I don't think SE is going anywhere soon, and if does, then you can raise the issue on Meta.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you can take solace in is that the literal *site* isn't going to go offline.

People tend to forget the actual questions and answers will survive the site itself.

Answer (score 3):

In that sentence, I may offer, **he said two things**:

1. "**exciting news**" — he is not forbidden from describing news as such, especially when it's indeed exciting for him.
2. "**news for** [...] **our community members**" — as in, this is news intended for us too.

But then he said it in a contracted way, capable of *hinting at* things beyond what he actually said.

The potential in this practice of language is proven by your question.

Given that all your future reassurances will come from the same source (as in, SO), you may, at this point, decide to pay very close attention to every detail.