# Open feedback and questions for Philippe (regarding communication around the AI policy rollout)

Tags: discussion

For context: Philippe, you have published [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928), to which, one of my responses was [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389945).

I have received your response in the form of a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes?page=2&tab=scoredesc#comment1301524_389945), which, for the sake of a duly structured response, I wish to address here. I will use my observations as the basis for questions that I will pose at the end.

Philippe, I expect, you wrote in your quality as VP of Community at SE. (Admittedly, It's not very clear for me what that exactly means, but I sense that the impact of that role is often in some overlap with the impact of a Public Relations Manager. (Corrections welcome.))

(**Update:** the response post I mention had now been deleted. This also brings the visibility of that comment in question.)

The [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes?page=2&tab=scoredesc#comment1301524_389945) in question:

> I have to say this is a new one for me. Never quite been accused of something like this before. For the record, 1) I don't play those games, this stuff is too important, and 2) I've got enough real problems to worry about without creating another one by doing something stupid like is alleged here. Levente, I'm sorry if my writing style was in some way triggering. That post was the summation of several team member's work and it's not alway easy to integrate into one cohesive narrative.

---

I observe the following:

> I'm sorry if my writing style was in some way triggering

Wikipedia has an entry on [non-apology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-apology_apology), which, in its "[Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-apology_apology#Examples)" section, names the variant that you delivered: **Ifpology**.

I expect anyone in the role of VP of Community at SE to be familiar with this knowledge.

I also expect from the VP of Community at SE that when it comes to the notion of an apology, they will either properly commit to it, or, if that's not their intent, then they have the knowledgeability and integrity to entirely omit it from their communication.

> by doing something stupid like is alleged here

I invite you to observe risks involving this statement:

- I feel, if I was to use the word "stupid" in any, *any* context or relation in a post that confronts your position, I feel, that would carry the risk of the rapid deletion of said content, and quite possibly an accompanying suspension for me. Which also would prevent me from participating in the possibly most important discussion in SE's history.
- What risk had *you* taken, on the other hand?

  Visibly enough, you meant that it was the *act* that I alleged that was stupid.

  Nevertheless, by [formulating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366149) the way you did, you opened up the risk that a number of readers may give themselves the permission to interpret it as if it was the *allegation* that I made, that was stupid; which is only a hairline away from implying that the one who made the allegation is the worthy recipient of the qualification.

  With your experience in community management, I expect, you are familiar with the ins and outs of subtly managing/influencing public sentiment. Accordingly, you could have easily recognized and avoided the named risk, but you did not. Why not?

> I don't play those games, this stuff is too important

For an experiment, I have pasted your comment into an empty comment field, and had removed:

- the substring "this stuff"; I got:

  `121 characters left`
- the substring "this stuff is too important"; I got:

  `138 characters left`

You had that much budget to express yourself, to speak your mind, to talk to me, to talk to us.

Yet, while talking about

- this standoff we have here,
- this untenable schism between SE and community,
- this conflict between SE and the creators about values,
- this crisis of unalignment between SE and the community,
- SE's uncertain future,
- this threat that looms large over the fate of the platform,
- this unprecedented challenge noone seems to have a viable idea how to reassuringly solve,

the thing that comes off of the top of your head is: "this stuff".

You are, naturally, allowed to put it like that.

Yet, I observe, this is [dudebro](https://www.salon.com/2013/09/17/how_dudebros_are_ruining_the_tech_industry_newscred/) talk.

It's quite easy to see though that the mindset you allowed an insight into, is not yours only; the concept you hold is evidently shaped by the dominant narrative, and accompanying language, at the SE headquarters, shared by decisionmaking SE staff.

---

Philippe, I'm concerned about the level of standards you seem to have set for yourself.

I can say the same for SE, the company.

In the conclusion of [your recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928), you seem to have forcefully reduced the entire case to only two possible alternatives, both of which seems to threaten to deliver the death knell to this platform.

You, thanks to our community, are quite visibly surrounded with a number of sensitive, intelligent and wise people who deliver broad perspectives and spectacularly valuable insights from many aspects of this challenge. Yet, I don't see how that cumulative knowledge and intelligence is nurtured and incorporated to ensure the future safety of the platform.

Your employer only recently had demonstrated utter inability to manage even fairly conventional challenges: [the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965) [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526) fell victim to was originally about a spectacularly incompetent roll-out of an inclusivity policy, and which fiasco, until this day, had not seen a satisfying resolution — even in the face of costing the platform the permanent loss of a vast trove of compassionate human intelligence. (See, all that compassionate intelligence that is unrepresented on the platform since then, is missing from the AIs' training data.)

Now, at the dawn of the age of AI, we are presented with a truly unprecedented, thus, unconventional challenge, that impacts not only SE and this community, but entire societies. Our entire species.

Where do you, where does your employer (SE), where does the owner of your employer (Prosus) draw the confidence from that it is you and only you who had made the right assessment, and who is solely qualified to deal with this challenge?

The community of unpaid volunteers had expressed that they don't have the capacity to ensure the factual correctness of posts that originate from AI source. If you nevertheless force AI content here, you seem to risk [SE becoming a mass disinformation platform, sabotaging humanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389912).

I'm quite convinced that that would be bad enough to bring the platform to its knees anyways. Are you willing to risk that, only so that Prosus gets a last chance to at least break even on their investment?

What kind of fallout do you expect from that? Do you plan to stick around for accountablity for the impacts of your decision?

Are you willing to believe that a better alternative could be possible?

What kind of, and what amount of research have you conducted into directions that would ensure the future operation of SE, but no ROI for Prosus? What did you consider and what kind of prospects have you identified? Are you willing to share that? Please do.

Comment: This almost seems like something you need to hash out in  a chat room, with a referee.

Comment: @W.O. how do you mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I cannot begin to explain what this post is supposed to accomplish. As well as your previous post (which got deleted shortly after posting this?) What do you want exactly? Because right now it feels like you're just trying to start a fight out of nowhere

Comment: @MissSkooter I wish that SE is managed by a team who I can feel is worthy of managing this wealth of human knowledge and collaboration. I wish to see that they are sufficiently aware enough of their responsiblity, and the consequences/weight of their decisions.

Comment: Great, and your proof that they're not is that Philippe got frustrated over your unfounded claim that he wrote a GPT answer?

Comment: @MissSkooter part of my proof is from 2019, that I linked, and part of my proof is that they don't seem to have improved much since.

Comment: It's not a fight I wanted to start. It's authentic, responsible introspection, free from the distractions of capitalist considerations of money, which I wanted to start.

Comment: It's a personal letter, not a question fitting Stack Exchange. Should be closed and deleted, not related to strike.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack o.k. I see that I have failed on the account of separation of concerns. The questions that I pose at the bottom, I believe are important and necessary. I should have posted them separately from my personal crusade for justice.

Answer (score 21):

This is a lot of words spent on something pointless. You perceived, incorrectly, that Phillipe was intentionally "taunting" us all by using a few phrases (in a very long post!) that resemble ChatGPT-style writing. Phillipe has said that he wasn't "taunting" anyone, and it seems that you are the only person who thinks he was.

Phillipe's comment responding to you was short because no comment was needed. His apology recognises no harm caused, because no harm was actually caused. Using stock phrases like *"it is worth noting that ..."* is not offensive or harmful in any way, those phrases are used by millions of human beings every day and it's unremarkable that they appeared in Phillipe's post.

Comment: I appreciate the "touch some grass", and I can share that I actually do that, literally, a lot (by taking walks in nature), but I also feel that this very slogan is becoming a device for expressing, and inviting intolerance. Actually, it is a device for sentiment management. It is a device for nurturing and deepening tribalism. Sharing for awareness.

Comment: "His apology recognises no harm caused, because ..." as I have written in my post: if he does not recognise harm caused, he should stay away from the concept of an apology. Else he only makes it worse.

Comment: One more thing, since you refer a lot to my other post which I referenced. I feel that that post of mine was available for receiving as many downvotes as it deserved (-42/+3 at the time of deletion). Now however I feel that I may continue to receive downvotes _here_ over the content of that _other_ post. Perhaps based on, and addressed to my person, as opposed to the considerations that I introduce here. Which are _different_ considerations. This all demonstrates that Philippe's comment had the potential to smear my character; which, all the more would be worthy of discussion & awareness.

Comment: Yeah, okay, admittedly, the style of my other, referred, now deleted post was also able to smear my character...

Comment: Your post here is reasonably getting downvoted because it has the same problems as your other post. If your point is that Phillipe shouldn't have written an apology, then yes, I agree, because he had nothing to apologise for (at least, nothing you had accused him of).

Comment: "it has the same problems as your other post" — I felt that this post was significantly different from the old, referred one. What are the common similarities between them?

Comment: Both are accusing Phillipe of something that everyone else can see he didn't do, and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: "everyone else can see he didn't do" — that's a bit tribalistic again, but I recognize the efficiency of your summary.